# I have unknown script injects in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

i am very confused because i have some script injects in google chrome on every website.  there is a "var pb_blacklist" with an array of (porn) urls. and a whitelist with google urls. Is this a normal google chrome filter oder something which i have on my computer?
its just in chrome not on other brothers like opera.

Maybe someone have the same and any idea..

here a screenshot of the webdev console

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is because extension PoperBlocker